# Improving performance of loops in python

Tags: python, pandas

I can't think another way to optimize my code. I used a nested for loop and my computer simply crashes. So I think the problem is my code. I'd like some help.

I need to check if a list of strings(basically words) is in the rows of a column of my df. It needs to go through each row and check if the word is in there. I thought it wouldn't be so difficult. Well I was terribly wrong. I imported the excel files. There are 3 in total.

```
filename='XXXX'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname='Data',index_col=0)`

df.columns:[['text', 'date', 'books', 'price']]


list_1 = ['apple', 'orange' , 'lime', 'pear']
list_2 = ['#loveapple', '#hateorange', '#likepear']

a = []
for word in df.text:
    for fruit in list_1:
        for tag in list_2:
            if fruit in word:
                fruit_list =fruit,word
            elif tag in word:
                tag_list = tag, word
                all_data = [fruit_list,tag_list]
                a.append(all_data)
```

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not numpy.int64

(I run in the past, but now it says TypeError)

I've been reading some of the posts but I can't find a case where you pass a whole list. The examples I found show a string only and it didn't work with a list. I also tried other tools like `xxx.str.contains`, but it didn't work.

I put the `word` twice so I can merge the 2 tables on `word`. However, it iterates with more than 35k rows so it's not working at all. I need to 'filter' the data first so I can analyze later on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear: is list_2 a list of strings? If so it should be initialised as list_2 = ['#loveapple', '#hateorange', '#likepear']

Comment: The third line above has invalid variables beginning with hash (#). You can't do that! If these are strings they should be quoted. What error do you get? Also, lists don't have a 'ppend' method!

Comment: @robbie yes, I just imported them as strings. Sorry! should be in quotations like you said.

Comment: @polarise, it was a typo. It's 'append' in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method on the pandas column.  Write a function that performs the comparison you wish to do, then apply that function to the appropriate column e.g.:

```
def compare_string(s):
    s = str(s)  # This is necessary in case there are empty values in your Excel file.  
    list_1 = ['apple', 'orange' , 'lime', 'pear']
    for fruit in list_1:
        if fruit in s:
            ...
```

Then you just call:

```
a = df.text.apply(compare_string)
```

If you have any empty values in your Excel file, they will be read as numpy.nan which is type numpy.int64.  That's probably why you're getting the type error.  Using the apply method and converting each element in the column to a string should take care of the TypeError and also improve the clarity/performance of your code.

Comment: Thanks. Please, it works fine when the list is inside the function. However, when I try to call it by putting their name i.e def compare_string(s):                    ` s = str(s)  # This is necessary in case there are empty values in your Excel file.  
    `list_1 = ['apple', 'orange' , 'lime', 'pear']
    for fruit in list_1:
        if fruit in s:`
When I run the code  `list_1 = list_1` it doens't work. I'm sure it's a list. Do you have any idea why this happens and how can I solve this?Thanks